# Can a single metal electrical box use two ground clips?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance, grounding

Inside a metal electrical box, can I use multiple ground clips (one for each conductor), or is it required that all ground conductors be twisted together and pigtailed into the same clip?

Comment: I can't speak for code, but technically, the results would be the same.

Comment: @DA01 yes, I know the results would be the same :D In fact, just wrapping the ground conductors against the box's wire clamps would have the same results... I'm asking about what's *correct*

Comment: "I'm asking about what's correct" = but that's making the assumption that code is always 'correct'. ;)

Comment: Fair enough! :-)

Comment: @DA01 if your goal is to pass inspection and/or avoid legal problems, then that's a pretty good assumption.

Comment: I don't assume code is ever the 'correct' way to do something in the sense that it's the best way to do something. It's often the tried-and-true or habitual reason to do something, though. Whether one decides to fight code on any particular issue is up to them and how much patience they have. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are carrying ground from one cable to the next, you should pigtail them. The ground clips are there to ground the box, not carry the ground to another cable; if one were to become disconnected, you would lose the ground in the circuit.

I prefer a screw connection in metal boxes over a ground clip.

Oh, and instead of a pigtail, you can use one of the green wire nuts with a hole in the center; that lets you pigtail with a bit less effort.

Comment: I have been attaching the line ground to the screw and the load ground to the clip. I'll check out green wire nuts